# MVVM on button click change visibility of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am pretty new to MVVM technology and cant seem to find the answer to my question anywhere. Can someone please give me a detailed example of how to get this to work. I am trying to on button click have a textbox show itself.

I have this so far.
WPF

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleBoolean, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}"
        Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,439,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />

<Button  Command="{Binding IsVisibleBoolean}" Height="32" Margin="526,401,142,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0"  Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"/>
```

C# Viewmodel

```
private bool _isVisibleBoolean = false;
    public bool IsVisibleBoolean
    {
        get { return _isVisibleBoolean; }
        set
        {
            if (_isVisibleBoolean == value)
                return;
            _isVisibleBoolean = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisibleBoolean");
        }
    }
```

and my booleanconvert class

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Boolean)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Command` property on `Button` should be bound to an `ICommand` object. You're binding it to a boolean property. If you want to keep this command based, create a class that implements `ICommand` and in the `Execute` method, set the `IsVisibleBoolean` of your view model.

Or the simpler approach: Use a `ToggleButton` instead of a `Button`.